# What is the name for the relation $x + y = \text{const.}$?

Tags: terminology

In my thesis, I want to explain that my experiment was set up in such a way that the sum of the two concentrations $~x~$ and $~y~$ is always constant,
$$
x + y = \text{const.}
$$

Is there a simple and concise term for this? I'm thinking of something like *isothermal*, which describes an area of equal temperature in chemistry, but in my case the *sum* of two different concentrations is always equal.

I'm asking here on **Mathematics Stack Exchange** because I believe that the term is likely a frequently used mathematical term. I seem to remember that there are different definitions of distances, with one of them being $~d=|x+y|~$ instead of $~d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~$, so maybe there is a term to describe this as an equidistant curve in relation to the former definition?

Comment: sum of concentrations is *conserved*; stay on the same contour line of $x+y$

Comment: $|x+y|$ isn't a norm in $R^2$, that's wrong.

Comment: You could say the two variables have a negative linear correlation.

Comment: @Jakobian, I just looked it up, what I was thinking of is the $L^p$ norm with $p=1$, which is also called *rectilinear distance* and is the distance used in *taxicab geometry*. Euclidean geometry uses the $L^p$ norm with $p=2$. You're probably right that it isn't a norm in $R^2$, but I never specified that. ;)

Comment: @Alfredo, I thought about using that, but it does not specify that the sum is constant. $y = -ax$ would also be negatively linearly correlated, but $x - ax \neq \text{const.}$

Answer (score 3):

In science, when a quantity remains constant, like the sum of concentrations in your example, we say it is *conserved.*

You could also say the sum of concentrations $x+y$ stays on the same contour line throughout the experiment.

That's all I can think of about this.

Good luck with your thesis!

Comment: +1 for the answer. I think another way to name this property would be invariance. The sum $x+y$ is invariant for the experiment. A third way would be to say that the sum $x+y$ is constrained to be a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the recognition. I think your ideas are good too, @MachineLearner

Answer (score 2):

I would describe the two concentrations  as **complementary**. It doesn't precisely specify the situation, so you will still have to display/explain the explicit equation that you've shown to us, but it will highlight the relationship. (Complementary does have a precise definition when applied to angles; it means two angles that add up to 90 degrees. I think using it in your case is a pretty obvious generalization.)